# HTML comment if without javascript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I know that I can display/hide content whether the browser is IE or not or even the version of IE. I was wondering if I can use other expressions too such as

```
<!--[if 1 == 0]-->
This should be hidden
<!--[endif]-->
```

The reason behind this is that I'm sending auto generated E-Mails and for me it would be easier to insert such comments in the template E-Mail instead of creating multiple templates.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a template system, then make this in your template. Anyway when you render the template you calculate the condition, but instead of printing "0 == 1" or "0 == 0", use the template's ability to print or not to print the following paragraph

Answer (score 0):

I know this would look like a long answer but I just wanted to divide the code into small functions each does its own job -*kind of*-, first select each element with a class name of `hasComment` in an array using `querySelectorAll` then pass this array to `updateHTML()` function, loop through its element and call `returnComment()` function for each item in the array.

The `returnComment()` function first call `hasComment()` function on the element passed to it, and using `.replace()` to get the exact string. Function `hasComment()` loop through the `child nodes` of the element and if the `nodeType` of the child node is `8` it then it's a comment, we return the text between the comment `<!--` and `-->`.

This `.replace(/\[|\]/ig, '');` omits the brackets to get value of either `show` or `hide` which according to it we "*hide*" or "*show*" the child `.contentDiv` div.

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/9916f0rm/)

```js
var commentDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.hasComment');

updateHTML(commentDivs);

function updateHTML(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var childDiv = arr[i].querySelector('.contentDiv'),
      showIt = returnComment(arr[i]);
    if (showIt == 'show') {
      childDiv.style.display = 'block';
      console.log('Div-' + (i + 1) + ': shown');
    } else if (showIt == 'hide') {
      childDiv.style.display = 'none';
      console.log('Div-' + (i + 1) + ': hidden');
    }
  }
}

function returnComment(element) {
  var comment = hasComment(element);
  comment = comment.replace(/\[|\]/ig, '');
  return comment;
}

function hasComment(element) {
  for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (element.childNodes[i].nodeType == 8) {
      return element.childNodes[i].data;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hasComment">
  <!--[hide]-->
  <div class="contentDiv">Div -1: This should be hidden</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="hasComment">
  <!--[hide]-->
  <div class="contentDiv">Div -2: Again, This should be hidden</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="hasComment">
  <!--[show]-->
  <div class="contentDiv">Div -3: But this should be shown</div>
</div>
```

### ----------

**Notes:**

- Wrapping the all contents of each `.hasComment` elements making controlling the content easier.
- The above solution only work on the very top level of `.hasComment` element children, so if you have other comments inside `.contentDiv` these comments won't be affected.
  [**Demo Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/9916f0rm/3/)
- You could  probably use `[if 1==0]` for "templating" like in your code then use `eval()` or more complex regex to check upon it, but IMHO I think using `show` and `hide` look easier and mostly less bugs as you this over and over through your document.
- More details about `nodeType`:

  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType
  - https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType
  - http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodetype.asp

Comment: Remember this is for **emails**, so this JS most likely won't function properly at all.  EDIT: Just re-read and saw they did mention *templates*, so  *if* they are generating from template before sending, then it is doable.

Comment: To be honest I've never worked with emails templating, I just wanted to show a solution in general.. Also if it is just for showing and hiding he can use CSS

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing for **email** clients, no this isn't possible. You need to figure out how different clients can be targeted. Then set the `display` property via CSS to whatever is affected.

Ideally, your *emails* shouldn't need any kind of crazy logic like this. It is a smell that your email is bad. Not to mention, anything you put in the email itself is viewable, all someone needs to do is turn off HTML rendering or view the source.